# Limit the number of child pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this html structure:

```
<home>
 <Web>
   <web 1>
   <web 2>
   <web 3>
   <web 4>
   <web 5>
   <web 6>
   <web 7>
 </web>
 <Print>
   <Print 1>
   <Print 2>
   <Print 3>
   <Print 4>
   <Print 5>
 </print>
 <Art>
   <Art 1>
   <Art 2>
   <Art 3>
   <Art 4>
   <Art 5>
   <Art 6>
 </art>
</home>
```

I use this to display the grandchildren content while hiding its parent

```
<?php $counter = 1 ?>
<div class="row-fluid">

<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
while ( have_posts() ) {
the_post();

$args=array(
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post__not_in' => array(4,368,358,354),
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post__in' => $pageIDs
);

$childpages = new WP_Query($args);

if($childpages->post_count > 0) { /* display the children content  */
    while ($childpages->have_posts()) {
         $childpages->the_post(); ?>
<div class="span4">
            <?php 
        echo "<h2>".get_the_title()."</h2>";
                echo the_content(); 
    ?>
</div>
<? if ($counter % 3 == 0): ?>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php $counter++; ?>

   <?php }
}
wp_reset_query();
}
}

?>
</div>
```

At the moment all grandchildren are displayed, how do I limit the number of grandchildren to be 3 per type (3 for the print, 3 for the web and 3 for the art)?

Comment: 'posts_per_page' => '3', it makes some sense? Also why do you have 2 queries? the_post() and WP_Query?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure, I am 2 days on it and I have tried so many things and I am now fairly confused. How would you do so that I display 3 grandchildren title and content and it parent titles?

Comment: 'posts_per_page' => '3' will only show me 3 grandchildrens of only 1 child and stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would try to not use more queries then required. Assuming you know (or know how to get) the `$id` (*as an integer*) of the parent post, use [the post_parent parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters):

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'page',
    'posts_per_page'    => 3,
    'post_parent'       => $id,
    'orderby'           => 'menu_order',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'post__not_in'      => array(4,368,358,354),
);
$childpages = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $childpages->have_posts() ) :
?>
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <?php
    while ( $childpages->have_posts() ) :
        $childpages->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="span4">
            <h2>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    endwhile;
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Try #2:

```
<div class="row-fluid">  
<?php
$args = array(
    'child_of' => 4,
    'parent' => 0,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
); 
$childrens = query_posts('showposts=100&post_parent=4&post_type=page&orderby=menu_order&order=asc');

foreach ( $childrens as $children ) :
    query_posts('showposts=3&post_parent='.$children->ID.'&post_type=page&orderby=menu_order&order=asc');
    if ( have_posts ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
            <div class="span4">
                <h2>
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </h2>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
<?php
        endwhile;
    endif;
endforeach;
?>
</div>
```

Let me know please what you got with this code examples.

Comment: Thanks! The first bit of code only show me 3 grandchildrens of 1 child but I need to show 3 grandchildren for each 3 child

Comment: Yes, but if instead of 'post_parent' => $id, if you insert it like 'post_parent' => array(1,2,3), where the numbers are the id's of your child pages, all should go fine. Other way is to get all your child id's first automatically. Or did you tried the second code?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in above comment. post_parent can't be an array, it's an integer as i told also in my answer :P

Comment: no luck :( added this tot he query:  'post_parent' => array(368,358,354), and I still only get 3 grandchilds of 354 . I now try the other code you provide

Comment: with your second bit of code I get this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object in

Comment: yep no array for post_parent so abck to square 1 :(

Comment: still Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object i

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23529/discussion-between-gravuj-miklos-henrich-and-rob-m)