# Foreach loop on a wp database query

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WordPress as my favourite cms software. Have worked with different WordPress specific queries like `WP_Query`, `get_posts`, `query_posts`, etc.

My question would be about the programming side. What if I ever will need to use for example a `foreach` loop inside a specific WordPress query->loop? I guess, sometimes it is not necesary to use wp loop inside another wp loop and it is recommended to use a simple php loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand how your question relates to the title, "...resulted in a string"

Comment: you're right. excuse me please. i guess a wp db query in most of cases can be an array or object

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Good fix on the title.

Comment: thank you :) things are so fast here, even the people :)

Comment: Please use google and consult the worpdress manual before asking a question: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_in_Action

Comment: Thank you. I know the combination with wp query->while cycle->wp query. I was just thinking about the foreach loop situations. I think now i got enough informations to move one step forward :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. There are situations when it is not required to do another database query in an existing loop. In this situations you can use the `foreach` loop.

*Example:*

```
$childrens = query_posts('showposts=10&&post_type=post');
foreach ( $childrens as $children ) {
    // dos tuff here
}
```

To see data stored in `$children`, use `print_r()`:

```
print_r( $childrens );
```

`$children->ID` is an example of an object property.

Let me know.

**Edit:** More documentations about `foreach`, here: [php-net foreach loops](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: So what if i have a query, inside the loop a foreach loop and inside the foreach loop another wp query?

Comment: Yes, it's okay, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571073/limit-the-number-of-child-pages/14571746#14571746 the second example code.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop inside another loop:

```
<?php while(have_posts()): the_post() ?>

    <h2><?php the_title() ?></h2>
    <?php
        // preserve global post variable
        global $post; $temp = $post;
        $args = array('posts_per_page'=>3);
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'terms' => array('featured'),
                'field' => 'slug',
            )
        );
        $new_query = new WP_Query($args);
        while($new_query->have_posts()): $new_query->the_post();
    ?>
    <h3>Featured: <?php the_title() ?></h2>
    <?php endwhile; $post = $temp; wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

The code above displays 3 latest posts in the category "Featured".

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need* to use `foreach`, but you can if you choose to.

The current version of WordPress (3.5 and lower), doesn't implement [interators](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php), but it provides some methods that have the functionality of an iterator.

For example `$query->`[`have_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) will advance to the next post. But you'll still need to setup WP globals using `$query->the_post()` before using functions valid within "[the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)", because those functions rely on global variables

Comment: You mean it's not a best practice?

Comment: It depends what you do in the loop. If you call functions like `get_the_title()` that get the post title from a global variable, obviously they will return the wrong result because both loops use the same variable. So in this case, yes, it is a bad practice according to WP standards

Answer (score 0):

While it's completely up to you how you structure your pages, there are definitely use cases for inner loops inside of `The Loop` in WordPress.

Say you've got an index page with a listing of posts, and under each post you want to list "related posts." You might, for example, loop through your posts and then use `WP_Query` to `foreach` through recent posts with the same tags.